# Titanium 5.1.1.GA SDK image file not upload in ios

Tags: ios, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

Here is my HTTPClient code for uploading image to server. The same works in 3.5.0.GA SDK and 4.1.0.GA SDK but not working in new SDK 5.1.1.GA and 5.1.2.GA.

```
var filename = "sample.png";
//Pointer to the file to be uploaded.
var uploadingFile = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, filename);

Ti.API.info('uploadingFile ' + uploadingFile.exists());
//We are creating a new xhr instead of calling the existing one because we dont want timeout when uploading data.
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    validatesSecureCertificate : false,
    enableKeepAlive : true,
    onload : function() {
        uploadingFile = null;
        Ti.API.info('Success '+tthis.responseText);         
    },
    onerror : function(data) {
        uploadingFile = null;
        Ti.API.info('this.status '+this.status);
    }
});

xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
    var uploadTime = new Date();
    Ti.API.info('UPLOADING PROGRESS: ' + progress + ' ' + uploadTime.getHours() + ":" + uploadTime.getMinutes() + ":" + uploadTime.getSeconds());
};

xhr.open('POST', httpClient.getUserDomainInfo(config.URLs.imageupload, tenant));
xhr.send({
    file : uploadingFile.read(),
    claimId : claimID,
    filename : filename,
    description : ''
});
```

Error status comes as 500 Internal Server Error.

Is that problem in SDK or anything i need to change in my code.

Please help me.

Comment: 500 error means your server is busy or not responding at that time. Please check your url is working fine or not.

Comment: you could also have an error in your server upload script

Comment: Same URL and same code works in 3.5.0.GA SDK and 4.1.0.GA SDK. So my assumption is server upload script good. Just now tried in 4.1.0GA it worked. Again i tried in 5.1.1GA its not worked.

Comment: I encounter the same issue. Still investigating for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The below code demonstrate the file upload. Modify according to your code.

```
f1 = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,<image name>);
i1 = f1.read();
xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open('POST','<url to call>', false); // false makes it synchronous
xhr.onload = function() { handleAfterSentRouting(this.responseText);   };
xhr.send({media1: i1}); // media1 is the field the file information is in when you upload
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered the same and the solution after weeks where very simple you just need to make another web service page on server only for the file upload without passing any other text parameters, in your case edit your xhr.send params to only include your file as follows:

```
xhr.send({
    file : uploadingFile
});
```

so make another xhr function related to another web server page for your other variables:

```
claimId : claimID,
filename : filename,
description : ''
```

It works ;)